# MVC and knockout model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, model-binding

I am trying to create a load on inputs on in my MVC application to be picked up by the MVC model binder to populate my view model. It's not working and I don't know why.

Here is a snippet of knockout with which I am hoping to create the inputs for the model binder to pick up:

```
        <div data-bind="foreach: witnesses">
            <input data-bind="attr: { name: 'Witnesses[' + $index() + '].firstName', value: firstName}" />
            <input data-bind="attr: { name: 'Witnesses[' + $index() + '].lastName', value: lastName}" />
            <!-- more fields here -->
        </div>
```

Here is snippet of the view model in C#:

```
public class GraffitiViewModel
{
    // view model
    public List<Witness> Witnesses;
}

public class Witness
{
    public string firstName { get; set;}
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string telephone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string propertyNameNumber { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
}
```

The inputs are being successfully passed to the server in the Request.Form, but they are not binding to the view model. Anyone have any idea why? My only other option is to step through the MVC source code to find out where the model binding is happening and why it's not working.

Mark

Comment: `Witnesses` should be also a property! `public class GraffitiViewModel
{
    // view model
    public List<Witness> Witnesses { get; set; }
}`

Comment: The attr binding part was fine `attr: { name: 'Witnesses[' + $index() + '].firstName` can you try to change it back now that your `Witnesses` is a property?

Comment: I did but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are trying to set name attribute by this 'Witnesses[' + $index() + '].firstName.
so first thing you can use it with $parent but instead of this you can directly use propery name. and as suggested by @[nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv), first make witnesses a property.

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: witnesses">
    <input data-bind="attr: { name: $parent.witnesses()[$index()].firstName, value: firstName}" />
   <input data-bind="attr: { name: $parent.witnesses()[$index()].lastName, value: lastName}" />
<!-- more fields here -->
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3Yze/

Comment: I have modified my code so that it looks like the above and I have changed the Witnesses field to be a property. I'm still getting null on my Witnesses property on postback though. Any ideas? Also, where is the documentation for $parent and $index?

Comment: Found the documentation! Pity the knockout site doesn't have a search

Answer (score 0):

Hi thee nemesv and alklesh

My view model is binding successfully now, thanks for your help. The syntax suggested did not work so I reverted to:

```
<input data-bind="attr: { name: 'Witnesses[' + $index() + '].firstName', value: firstName}" />
```

This isn't pretty but it works, so I am happy. I may revisit it and try to make it neater but I've spent enough time on it now so I'm moving on.

Thanks again for your help.

Mark